# Changing main language to Danish - Babel not working

Tags: texstudio, babel, languages

I use TexStudio as my editor, and I'm having problems with changing the language to Danish, so I can use the letters 'æ', 'ø', and 'å'. My document also contains an abstract in English, so I wrote the following in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, danish]{babel}
```

However it seems to have no effect. I've tried deleting the .aux file and recompiling/saving and building the document again with no change.

EDIT: I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "pleasework".tex
```

Comment: don't just say it is not working: what error do you get (exact error message from the log file) You have specified UTF-8 are you sure the file is saved in that encoding? (that being the most common error in this area)

Comment: Language has nothing to do with whether or not æøå can be used. The encoding does (both input encoding and to a lesser extend the font encoding, it is recommended to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: BTW: please remember to post full minimal examples (that others can just copy and test as is) instead of sniplets like this. Then we do not need to guess the rest of your preamble and document class.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that ... I do get one error, I'l edit the post. Furthermore, it is indeed using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: This looks more as if `pdflatex` is not starting up. And you say you could compile in `pdflatex` when you use another language than Danish? Have you installed the Danish package for `babel`?

Comment: I can compile when using other languages yes, and I do have the package.

Comment: the error says pdflatex did not start so it is unrelated to your input document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works perfectly fine for me (in TeXnic-Center).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %thanks's daleif
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, danish]{babel}

\begin{document}

Let's try some danish stuff: æ, ø, å

\end{document}
```

[image]

One thing you have to pay attention to is that not only the `inputenc` must be set to `utf8`, but also your .tex-file must be saved in UTF8 encoding, not e.g. ASCII. You should be able to choose the file encoding somewhere under *save as* probably, although I can really hardly believe that any halfway modern editor is using another encoding by default. Do you get any additional errors, or are the symbols just not printed?

Comment: Also remember `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: As far as I can see it's using UTF-8 encoding (I can see it in the bottom right corner and when I go under Edit --> Setup encoding)

Comment: Okay, I don't know why ... (well, obviously I made a mistake somewhere) but I opened a new document, pasted your code from above and it worked. Thanks for the help, despite my certainty I evidently made an error along the way.